# R: Connect to Greenplum Database

Tags: r, database, greenplum

I’d like to preface by saying that I’m relatively competent at R and SQL, but have very little knowledge of database connections/maintenance.

On my Windows computer, I have a connection to a Greenplum database in both SAS and Toad that works fine, and I’d like to make the same connection in R. My main problem is determining what the actual name is of my driver/server/database. Here’s my "work" so far:

```
# Install RODBC
install.packages(“RODBC”)

# Create connection to database
connect <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="driver=
                              {Greenplum};
                              server=“ServerName”;
                              database=“DataBase”;
                              trusted_connection=true")
```

I just really don’t know where to find the name of my server or database (database I can probably figure out). Given I have a connection in Toad/SAS, is there an easy way to find the name of the server I’m connected to?

Comment: SAS and Toad will have the hostname you connect with.  The database name can be obtained from running this in Toad: select current_database();

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this reference guide: https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/gp-r/blob/master/HomePage.md#rpostgresql

```
DBNAME = 'marketing'
HOST   = '10.110.134.123'

# Create a driver
drv <- dbDriver( "PostgreSQL" )
# Create the database connection
con <- dbConnect( drv, dbname = DBNAME, host = HOST )

# Create the SQL query string. Include a semi-colon to terminate
querystring =   'SELECT countryname, income, babies FROM country_table;'
# Execute the query and return results as a data frame
countries   = dbGetQuery( con, querystring )

# Plot the results
plot( countries$income, countries$babies )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's the Host part that I can't get past. The user above helped me find the specific database name, but I can't find (or don't know where to look) the Host IP or server name.

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal also provides PivotalR lib in CRAN.